# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get this error, when I try to run my code:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import _ from "lodash";

class TableBody extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { data, columns } = this.props;
    return (
      <tbody>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <tr>
            {columns.map((column) => (
              <td>{_.get(item, column.path)}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    );
  }
}

export default TableBody;
```

Comment: It seems either `data` or `columns` is undefined.

Comment: How are you using your TableBody component? Have you set columns to something there? Also, try to move the const .. = this.props before the render function. That's what I always do, not sure if that's the problem though

Comment: can u add the data and columns value as well?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if data is something that comes from a remote request it is undefined at the first render, until a response comes. Or maybe you are doing some computation in the parent component in which data is undefined when the component gets render. You can write you code like this:

```
const { data = [], columns = [] } = this.props;
```

Which set the values to an empty array if they are undefined.

However be sure that you are passing an array and not something else.